# strange behaviour of standard C++ string library

Tags: c++, string

I started writing program for findings substrings, but it doesn't work and it always found substring. It was strange behaviour so I wrote simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str;
    str = "aaaa";
    unsigned found = str.find("bbbb");
    if(found!=std::string::npos){
        cout << "I FOUND IT!!!!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and it displays text "I FOUND IT!!!!" I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: seems no problem here: http://ideone.com/DfeGtM

Comment: Which compiler/stdlib are you using?

Comment: ideone is 32bit, where `sizeof(std::string::size_type) == sizeof(unsigned)`. In a 64 bit architecture like what this person has, `sizeof(size_type)` is probably 8 bytes, and zero extending `found` to 8 bytes will cause it to be different from `size_type`, which is `-1`.

Comment: why don't you make your own define? instead of using std::string::npos ?

Comment: Don't ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: I am using g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2 and it didn't show any warnings but problem was realy that my program is 64bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::string::find` returns a size_t

`std::string::npos` is defined as the maximum value that fits in a size_t, probably `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` for a 64bit program.

When you cast it to an unsigned int, this is probably 32bits and so `0xFFFFFFFF`

As `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF != 0xFFFFFFFF` you get the result you see.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled your exact code and ran it in VS2008 and it worked exactly as expected - so I don't think there is problem with the code at all.

EDIT: Ah good point from one of the commenters re found being unsigned int! Make it size_t type and I bet it will work, regardless of the machine architecture.

Answer (score 1):

string::npos is of type size_t and not of type integer, so on a 64 bit machine 'found' would have to be unsigned long or just size_t.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using the same type as is used by std::string::npos. On my Windows 7 PC, it's using 'unsigned int'. I tested your code and it works for me.
If you're in Visual Studio 2012 (using C++0x), then you can use type 'auto'.

```
auto found = str.find("bbbb");
```

Comment: On my C++ abstract virtual machine it's "size_t", not "unsigned int". Rather make sure you're using the correct type for all machines (which is what auto does, but he's unlikely to be using VS).